# PHP. Как убрать echo вывода строки от функции if( strpos (

Tags: php

Всем привет. Вывел и упорядочил данные на странице из строки.
Как можно визуально убрать найденную строку с страницы. При любых попытках это сделать, все ломается и слетает. Понимаю, что звучит абсурдно, ведь эту же строку использовал для вывода данных. Выглядит топорно и не могу ее даже спрятать, а изящного решения не могу придумать.

Скриншот и код прилагаю.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$search = "$utm";
$lines = file('../billtx/payprebill.txt');
foreach($lines as $num_line => $line_value)
{
    if(strpos($line_value, $search) !== FALSE)   
    echo "*$line_value<br>"; // КАК ПЕРЕСАТЬ ВИЗУАЛЬНО ВЫВОДИТЬ ECHO В HTML БЕЗ КРУШЕНИЯ ПОДСЧЕТА";
    $input_string = "$line_value";
    $sub = "$search"; 
            if (strpos($input_string, $sub) !== false)
            {
                    $string = "$input_string"; 
                    $str_arr = preg_split ("/\,/", $string); 
                    //print_r($str_arr); // выводит конструкцию arr
                    $string = "$line_value"; 
                    $str_arr = preg_split ("/\,/", $string); 
                    //print_r($str_arr);  // выводит конструкцию arr
            }
            }

        echo '*Почтовый индекс: ' . $str_arr[0] . '</br>';
        echo '*Имя: ' . $str_arr[1] . '</br>';
        echo '*Емейл: ' . $str_arr[2] . '</br>';
```

Comment: закомментировать строку с ```echo```???

Comment: Не используйте if без фигурных скобок. Никогда.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вам правильно подсказали в комментариях, тут все дело в отсутствии фигурных скобок в `if(strpos($line_value, $search) !== FALSE)`.

Если вы уберете, следующее за ним `echo "*$line_value<br>"`, то в данной условие будет попадать строка `$input_string = "$line_value"`.

Поэтому вам нужно либо убирать и `if(strpos($line_value, $search) !== FALSE)`, либо добавить фигурные скобки.

```
if(strpos($line_value, $search) !== FALSE) {
    $input_string = "$line_value";
    $sub = "$search"; 
            if (strpos($input_string, $sub) !== false)
            {
                    $string = "$input_string"; 
                    $str_arr = preg_split ("/\,/", $string); 
                    //print_r($str_arr); // выводит конструкцию arr
                    $string = "$line_value"; 
                    $str_arr = preg_split ("/\,/", $string); 
                    //print_r($str_arr);  // выводит конструкцию arr
            }
            }

        echo '*Почтовый индекс: ' . $str_arr[0] . '</br>';
        echo '*Имя: ' . $str_arr[1] . '</br>';
        echo '*Емейл: ' . $str_arr[2] . '</br>';
}
```

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы, в том числе и другие комментарии. Применил Ваш вариант. Но теперь проблема. Данные, которые распределил по массивам. Бесконечно выводятся на странице. Скриншот: https://prnt.sc/Ftvna7kJ7Uq6

Как это можно решить?

Comment: Решил проблему: Называется невнимательность!

Лишние кавычки были foreach($lines as $num_line => $line_value)
{  <- после далее закрывающая

Comment: @Mike она была не лишняя, просто у вас отсутствует закрывающая